# Python, Selenium. Google Chrome. Web Scraping. How to navigate between 'tabs' in website

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

im quite noob in python and right now building up a web scraper in Selenium that would take all URL's for products in the clicked 'tab' on web page. But my code take the URL's from the first 'tab'. Code below. Thank you guys. Im starting to be kind of frustrated lol.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXNt5.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from lxml import html 


PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = 'https://www.alza.sk/vypredaj-akcia-zlava/e0.htm'

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tabs"]/ul/li[2]').click()

links = []

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'blockFilter')))
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='name browsinglink impression-binded']")
    
    for i in link:
        links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

finally:
    driver.quit()

print(links)
```

Answer (score 3):

To select current tab:

```py
current_tab = driver.current_window_handle
```

To switch between tabs:

```py
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Assuming you have the new tab url as `TAB_URL`, you should try:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(TAB_URL).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

---

Also, apparently the `li` doesn't have a *click* event, are you sure this element you are getting `'//*[@id="tabs"]/ul/li[2]'` has the `aria-selected` property set to `true` or any of these classes: `ui-tabs-active` `ui-state-active`?

If not, you should call *click* on the `a` tag inside this `li`.

Then you should increase the *timeout* parameter of your `WebDriverWait` to guarantee that the *div* is loaded.

Comment: Hi thank you. But those are not tabs in google chrome but tabs element specificly in web site. Im trying your method from what i understand after clicking the button it should store the newly formed page with driver.current_window_handle but its not working. Its giving me the out of the range error.

Comment: yes the element have aria-selected = true. I can actually see driver clicking on that tab and loading the product in that tab but when i try to scrape the href's of products with a loop its giving me hrfe's from first tab lol. im wondering if there is some other element above the 'product' elements that  a have to specifly select with xpath so it is loading the correct href's

Comment: You mean something like this? It's not working.                                                                                    `try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'browsingitemcontainer')))                                                                                                                       
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='name browsinglink impression-binded']")
    
    for i in link:
        links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

finally:
    driver.quit()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230285/discussion-between-renan-lopes-and-ladislaff).